# PhantomJS load issues in fresh Volt app

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, voltrb, opalrb

I tried to run

```
BROWSER=phantom rspec spec
```

on a newly created Volt App and hit the following error:

```
WARNING: LoadError: cannot load such file -- volt/views/notices/index
# ... continues for some time ...
```

This was a pretty default spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'sample integration test', type: :feature do
  # An example integration spec, this will only be run if ENV['BROWSER'] is
  # specified.  Current values for ENV['BROWSER'] are 'firefox' and 'phantom'
  it 'should load the page' do
    visit '/'

    expect(page).to have_content('Home')
    puts '======'
  end
end
```

Keep in mind, this is a default spec setup. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What version of volt are you runnign?

Comment: @Ryan I'm on 0.9.5pre4